# how to change the default install path of WINE?

Tags: ubuntu, wine

Wine(5.0.2) is installed to /opt directory by default in ubuntu.
But my /opt directory is out of space.
How can I change the default install path of WINE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compile from sources and install wherever you want
2. Create a symbolic link `ln -s /mnt/where_you_have_space/directory /opt/wine`
3. `mount --bind /mnt/where_you_have_space/directory /opt/wine`